# WCF AJAX Response fail when Using System.Array as a DataMember

Tags: ajax, wcf, json, datamember, system.array

When i m trying to get `Sytem.Array` As data member in Json Class object it gives failure response .

My WCf web-service i am using following method `userActivities` which return  class `Activity`.I  have set parameter in class `Activity` from Ajax .

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Activity userActivities(Activity activity, string action);
}

[DataContract]
partial class Activity
{

}
```

And in the MyService.cs Class of Service is

```
public Activity userActivities(Activity activity, string action)
{
    if (action.ToLower() == "myactivities")
    {
      activity.get_MyActivities();
    }
    return activity;
}
```

And Class Activity is :

```
[DataMember]
public int userID;

[DataMember]
public Array _getList_MyActivities;

public void get_MyActivities()
{
    _DL_Activity = new DL_Activity();
    if (this.userID > 0)
        this._getList_MyActivities = _DL_Activity.get_MyActivity(this.userID);

}
```

Comment: Please put you whole `Activity` class in one code block, it is difficult to understand your code, and why you are using `partial`?

Comment: Partial because we want put code separate from interface

Comment: What are you storing in `_getList_MyActivities`? `Activity`?

Comment: Rows of MY Activity like Ondate, Activity Type ,to_UserID ,from_UserID

Comment: These are all primitive data types or your custom classes? If custom classes, all should have `[DataContract]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134371/serializing-array-of-objects-to-json-in-wcf-to-comply-with-opensearch) post. According to this try decorating your service with `ServiceKnownType`.

Something like this

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(string))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(string[]))]
public interface IMyService
```

According to your comment you are storing different data types in the array, I guess you will need to put `typeof` for all items in array as `ServiceKnownType`.

Hope this works for you.